# jenkins does not detects jasmine tests failures

Tags: testing, junit, jenkins, jasmine

I set up grunt jasmine in order to be run by a jenkins job, but the output jUnit is not parsed by jenkins correctly. This is how the resulting XML looks like, where i obscured some details:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="obs" errors="0" tests="12" failures="1" time="0.435" timestamp="2013-11-07T14:47:04.141Z">
    <testcase assertions="13" classname="obs" name="obs" time="0.035"></testcase>
    <testcase assertions="7" classname="obs" name="obs" time="0.032"></testcase>
 ...
</testsuites>
```

Basically jenkins does not detect the failure. It shows all the tests as successful.

Did anybody met this problem?

jenkins version 1.521

Answer (score 0):

I found out this problem was fixed in `grunt-contrib-jasmine` version `0.5.2`